# Hover Styling CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to get my styling working properly for some hovering boxes that I created but it's not going too well...

I kind of have my general idea down.. which is as you hover over items items to the right become visible and so on... One of my biggest issues that I have been consistently having, this project included, is having items at width 100% so that all lines are the same size... but I can't get that to work here, so I have to manually place everything  in positions (i.e. left 500px etc.)

Another thing that has been giving me an issue with this, for the final hover where the part number shows up I can't get it to appear just to the right of the corresponding product (it used to all appear on 1 line), but instead I had to position it relatively, and then change up the positioning so now I get a space in between each line when I hover over the product...

Here is my fiddle... any help would be appreciated
    http://jsfiddle.net/H9CTe/1/

This would probably be the line we need to work with, but I could be completely wrong

```
#ipc_cases ul li ul li ul li ul {
     position: relative;
     top:-18px;
     left: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a reset [[1]](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Simply checking the `Normalized CSS`[[2]](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) box in `Fiddle Options` solves this.

http://jsfiddle.net/H9CTe/2/

(will update)